# showing amount of entries from custom select datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

i am customizing jquery datatables and what i wanted is to remove the default search and entries select and add custom search field and select field.

i have integrated the search successfully though i am struggling with select let me show you my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $tableinstance = $("#example").DataTable();

  $('#customsearchfield').keyup(function() {
    $tableinstance.search($(this).val()).draw();
  });

  $('#sort').change(function() {
    quantity = $(this).val().replace(/[a-z]/gi, ''); //removing chars from 10 ads per page and getting only quantity in integers
    $tableinstance.fnFilter([
      [quantity, 'asc']
    ]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="table-search">
  <input placeholder="Search Here" id="customsearchfield" />
  <div id="dropdown">
    <select id="sort">
      <option selected disabled="">Select Ads Quantity</option>
      <option>10 Ads per Page</option>
      <option>20 Ads per Page</option>
      <option>30 Ads per Page</option>
      <option>40 Ads per Page</option>
      <option>50 Ads per Page</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="cars-table">
  <table id="example">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" /></th>
        <th>Stock #</th>
        <th>Photo</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Make/Model/Trim</th>
        <th>Car Status</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>SitePoint1</td>
        <td>SitePoint</td>
        <td>SitePoint</td>
        <td>SitePoint</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">Awaiting Delivery</a>
          <img src="images/draft_22.png" />
        </td>
        <td>SitePoint2</td>
        <td>SitePoint</td>
        <td>SitePoint</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>SitePoint3</td>
        <td>SitePoint</td>
        <td>SitePoint</td>
        <td>SitePoint</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="reconditioning">Reconditioning</a>
          <img src="images/draft_25.png" />
        </td>
        <td>SitePoint4</td>
        <td>SitePoint</td>
        <td>SitePoint</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>SitePoint5</td>
        <td>SitePoint</td>
        <td>SitePoint</td>
        <td>SitePoint</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="ready">Ready For Sale</a>
          <img src="images/draft_27.png" />
        </td>
        <td>SitePoint</td>
        <td>SitePoint</td>
        <td>SitePoint</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>SitePoint6</td>
        <td>SitePoint</td>
        <td>SitePoint</td>
        <td>SitePoint</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="ready">Ready For Sale</a>
          <img src="images/draft_27.png" />
        </td>
        <td>SitePoint</td>
        <td>SitePoint</td>
        <td>SitePoint</td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>SitePoint7</td>
        <td>SitePoint</td>
        <td>SitePoint</td>
        <td>SitePoint</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="ready">Ready For Sale</a>
          <img src="images/draft_27.png" />
        </td>
        <td>SitePoint8</td>
        <td>SitePoint</td>
        <td>SitePoint</td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>SitePoint9</td>
        <td>SitePoint</td>
        <td>SitePoint</td>
        <td>SitePoint</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="ready">Ready For Sale</a>
          <img src="images/draft_27.png" />
        </td>
        <td>SitePoint</td>
        <td>SitePoint</td>
        <td>SitePoint</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

now i have an event of select onchange i have tried fnFilter and fnsort but none of them work for my requirement can anybody guide me how to add entries filter from custom select?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zc3aL6su/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using the default input/select fields and modify / style them later?
for instance, you can modify the select field text like so:

```
$tableinstance=$("#example").dataTable({
    "oLanguage": {
      // _MENU_ is the dropdown menu
      "sLengthMenu": "Select Ads Quantity _MENU_",
    }
});
```

Here is the [documentation](https://datatables.net/docs/DataTables/1.9.4/DataTable.defaults.oLanguage.html#sLengthMenu_details) for more examples.

Otherwise, here is how to set a custom [select field](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html)

**Edit**

Try this:

First, add value attribute to your select options instead of using Regex to get the values as integers to avoid unnecessary code.

```
// Add value attribute
<select id="sort">
    <option selected disabled="">Select Ads Quantity</option>
    <option value="10">10 Ads per Page</option>
    <option value="20">20 Ads per Page</option>
    <option value="30">30 Ads per Page</option>
    <option value="40">40 Ads per Page</option>
    <option value="50">50 Ads per Page</option>
</select>
```

Then add the `.change()` event just like you did in `.keyup()` event

```
$('#sort').change(function() {
  $tableinstance.search($(this).val()).draw();
});
```

Comment: hello awran! sorry for the late reply, my design is very customized and using the default layout will cause problems so what i did is add hid the original search and select and added the customized one, the above solution works for the by default select, can i use  my own select?

Comment: Hey @uneebmeer I've edited the answer, please check that out.

Comment: thanks awran! you wont believe i did it myself a few moments ago but i still appreciate your help keep up the good work :)